# Error in VSCode returning exit code 1 when running console.log("Hello world"); in javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I was trying to run my .js file in VSCode. But for some reason this line:

```js
console.log("Hello world!");
```

returns:

```
[Running] node "c:\Users\ukkis\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\My_code\JS\test.js"
"node" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.084 seconds
```

what happened?

Comment: _"Run"_ how, exactly?

Comment: It will help if you get VSCode to interpret Cyrillic as UTF8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you haven't installed `nodejs` Runtime JavaScript Engine.
To install:

- For Windows download and install from official website https://nodejs.org
- For Linux: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install nodejs`

Comment: Why do you think node isn't installed?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because that's the common error message. The same error happened with me ;)

Comment: Surely if node isn't installed they'd get `node command not found`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox VSCode runtime environment works somehow differently

Comment: @evolutionxbox - it is likely `�� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.` is non-UTF cyrillic for "node not found" ;)

Answer (score -2):

Try by writing node and then file name in the cmd panel.
[here is the reference img.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVh4l.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33330740)